# AFNetworking: get JSON and to UITableView

Tags: objective-c, json, afnetworking

I'd like to know how to get JSON data and output in `UITableView`.
I'm using AFNetWorking for HTTP communication.

When I build, the app crash with following message

```
-[_NSInlineData count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1091384f0
```

I have this code.

JSON(in localhost)

```
[{"id":"1","text":"aaa"},{"id":"2","text":"bbb"},{"id":"3","text":"ccc"}]
```

and get above JSON
iOS ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager* manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager GET:@"http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.php"
      parameters:nil
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
             self.jsonFromAFNetworking = responseObject;
             [_tableView reloadData];
             NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"%@", error);
         }];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* cellIdentifer = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifer forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifer];
    }
    NSDictionary* tempDict = [self.jsonFromAFNetworking objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [tempDict objectForKey:@"text"];
    return cell;
}
```

How do I fix it to get JSON and output in UITableView?

Comment: Are you getting the same json string in response? Or there is problem in receiving the data?

Comment: What line does the exception traceback identify as the failing line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFNetworking isn't recognizing your server's response as JSON. You're assuming `responseData` is an `NSArray`, but it's an `NSData`.

1. Delete `manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];` so your manager will use the JSON serializer.
2. Inspect `operation.responseString` in your success block. Make sure it looks like the valid JSON you expect.
3. Make sure the JSON strictly conforms to [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt). Use a JSON validator like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to double-check. (The JSON in your example is valid).
4. Make sure your server is sending the appropriate `Content-Type` header. These are acceptable by default: `application/json`, `text/json`, `text/javascript`.

If none of these resolve your issue, set a breakpoint and step through [the `AFJSONResponseSerializer` implementation](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLResponseSerialization.m#L222).

Answer (score 0):

Replace AFHTTPResponseSerializer with AFJSONResponseSerializer. So you should receive:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager* manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    // ... the rest is the same
```

Comment: @AaronBrager yes, but in this line 'manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];' it is replased with AFHTTPResponseSerializer.

Comment: Yeah, I just meant it would be easier to remove the line entirely. Sorry I wasn't clear.